# Configure Cisco AS2511-RJ as terminal server for Juniper SRX

Tags: cisco, juniper

I have a Cisco AS2511-RJ I am using as a terminal server to 3560 switches, I also have an SRX100 and SRX210 that I would like to connect to using the Cisco Terminal Server but I am unable to achieve this, I get gibberish when using the Terminal Server config for the Cisco devices, I would be grateful for help or directions if it is at all possible to connect to the SRX devices using the AS2511.

Comment: It's a little unclear, you get gibberish when you try to configure the 2511?  Or you get gibberish when you try to connect to the SRXs from the 2511?

Comment: When I try to connect to the SRX, seems my cable was bad, switched cables and I can connect, thanks though.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gibberish means the port speed is wrong -- or flow control isn't setup correctly and it's overflowing.

Nothing at all means the wiring is wrong. Don't assume Cisco and Juniper use the same pinouts. Of course, it could simply be DTE vs DCE (tx/rx swapped)

Here's how I have a line configured to access a 2948G-L3:

```
line ....
 session-timeout 30 
 no motd-banner
 exec-timeout 0 0
 modem DTR-active
 transport input telnet
 stopbits 1
 speed 38400
```

(authentication is required on that port)